# Cannot initialize SharePoint project item whenever a project is reopened

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I'm developing a SharePoint Visual Web Part for SharePoint 2016 with Visual Studio 2015. When I create a new web part all the relevant extensions initialize correctly. However, when I close Visual Studio and reopen it, the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.VisualWebPart" cannot be found.

The dialogue box suggests reinstalling the extension that provides the item type, but I'm not sure which extension provides it or how to identify it.

Furthermore, I'm running this on a server with strict access controls, and uninstalling and reinstalling programs is a lengthy process.

Is there a way to fix this error without having to reinstall, or if not, what extension needs to be reinstalled?

---

The full error:

`Cannot initialize the following SharePoint project item: 'VisualWebPart1'. This item requires a type provider that has the following ID, but this provider could not be found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.VisualWebPart.' Reinstall the extension that provides this item type or remove the item from your project.`

Answer (score 0):

So I found a pseudo-fix for the error. I say 'pseudo-fix' because the fix allows the project to Build and Deploy successfully, even though the error reappears once the project is reopened again (the project will Build and Deploy regardless of error).

Steps:

- Manually change the `Scope` in the `Feature1.feature` file from `"Web"` to `"Site"`
- Manually add `SupportedTrustLevels="All" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Site"` to the `ProjectItem` item in `SharePointProjectItem.spdata`

Solution found from [this Microsoft forum post here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6874cb6b-f77c-4b34-a4c6-d07e72ade070/the-partial-project-item-type-does-not-have-a-value-for-this-property-visual-studio?forum=sharepointdevelopment).